# Laravel 4 Query against other tables

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have 4 tables:

partners
users
phones
addresses

The addresses, phones, and partners table each have a *fk* to the id of the users table to allow a user->owner object environment.

The phones and addresses tables each have a *fk* to the id in the partners table.

The partners table has a primaryPhone and a primaryAddress field that stores the id to their primary address and phone number.

I want to be able to query all the partners associated with a user and at the same time draw into the array the information pertaining to their primary phone and primary address to display in a grid.

Is there a way to do this in a single query?

## partners controller (PartnersController.php)

```
public function index()
{

    $partners = Partners::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->get();

    return View::make('partners.showall')
        ->with('partners', $partners)
        ->with('title', 'partners')
        ->with('breadcrumb', 'View Partners');
}
```

Can I get the information for the $partner->primaryPhone into the partners array so that in the view I am able to do a foreach and display the data?

### Partners model (Partners.php)

```
public function phone()
{
   return $this->hasMany('Phone', 'partner_id')->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id);
}

public function primaryPhone($id)
{
   return $this->has('Phone', 'id')->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id);
}
```

### TABLE STRUCTURES

```
        CREATE TABLE `partners` (
        `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
        `firstName` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
        `lastName` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
        `spouseName` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
        `primaryPhone` int(11) NOT NULL,
        `primaryAddress` int(11) NOT NULL,
        `primaryEmail` int(11) NOT NULL,
        `greeting` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
        `birthDate` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
        `spouseBirthDate` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
        `anniversary` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
        `notes` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
        `profession` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
        `spouseProfession` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
        `pNewsletter` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
        `eNewsletter` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
        `partnerStatus` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
        `photoUrl` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
        `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
        `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
        PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
        UNIQUE KEY `partners_id_unique` (`id`)
      ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

      CREATE TABLE `phones` (
        `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        `partner_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
        `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
        `number` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
        `description` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
        `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
        `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
        PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
        UNIQUE KEY `phones_id_unique` (`id`)
      ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

      CREATE TABLE `addresses` (
        `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        `partner_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
        `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
        `city` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
        `state` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
        `country` int(11) NOT NULL,
        `postalcode` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
        `address_1` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
        `address_2` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
        `description` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
        `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
        `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
        PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
        UNIQUE KEY `addresses_id_unique` (`id`)
      ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

      CREATE TABLE `users` (
        `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        `email` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
        `firstName` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
        `lastName` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
        `phoneNumber` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
        `password` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
        `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
        `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
        PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
        UNIQUE KEY `users_id_unique` (`id`),
        UNIQUE KEY `users_email_unique` (`email`)
      ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you may be able to use eager loading to load in the related models that you want to show. Docs here: http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#eager-loading

I think this should work, although haven't tested it myself.

```
$partners = Partners::with('primaryPhone')->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$partners = Partners::with('phones')->with('adresses')->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->get();
 //Now you can loop through the partners
foreach($user->partners as $partner)
{
 echo $partner->primaryAdress();
 echo $partner->primaryPhone();
}
?>
```